# Comparing and returning dictionary string values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Trying to make a function that returns a list of values from the dictionary. If the plants are watered weekly, it would be appended into the list then later returned sorted. However, my code iterates each letter of 'weekly' instead of the whole string and I have no idea how to access the watering frequency of the dictionary items. Any explanations would be appreciated.

```
def weekly(plants_d):
    d = []
    for plant in plants_d:
        for plan in plants_d[plant]:
            if plan == "weekly":
                d.append[plan]
                    return sort(d)
weekly({'fern':'weekly', 'shamrock':'weekly', 'carnation':'weekly'})
# Should return like this: ['carnation','fern','shamrock']
```

Comment: `plants_d[plant]` is a string like `'weekly'`, so `for plan in plants_d[plant]` will loop over the individual characters.

Comment: Do you really have `return sort(d)` indented like that? It should be outside all the loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amending the previous answer so that only values with "weekly" are used:

```
>>> my_dict = {'fern':'weekly', 'shamrock':'weekly', 'carnation':'weekly', 'daffodil': 'monthly'}
>>> sorted(k for k, v in my_dict.items() if v == 'weekly')
['carnation', 'fern', 'shamrock']
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
for plan in plants_d[plant]:
```

is wrong. Since `plants_d[plant]` is a string like `"weekly"`, this is like

```
for plan in "weekly":
```

which will iterate over the letters in the string. Then when you do `if plan == "weekly":` it will never match, because `plan` is just a single letter like `"w"`.

You can simply use:

```
if plants_d[plan] == "weekly":
```

Or you can change the first loop to:

```
for plan_name, plan_frequency in plants_d.items():
    if plan_frequency == "weekly":
        d.append[plan_name]
```

See [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified way to achieve this is using `dict.keys()` which return the list of all the keys in `dict`. In order to sort the list, you may use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) as:

```
>>> my_dict = {'fern':'weekly', 'shamrock':'weekly', 'carnation':'weekly'}
>>> sorted(my_dict.keys())
['carnation', 'fern', 'shamrock']
```

---

Edit: If some the plans are monthly, firstly filter the monthly plans using `filter` or *dict comprehension*. Your code should be like:

```
>>> my_dict = {'fern':'weekly', 'shamrock':'weekly', 'carnation':'weekly', 
               'something': 'monthly'}
# using filter() as @brianpck has already mentioned 'dict comprehension' approach
# It is better to use brian's approach
>>> filtered_dict = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 'weekly', my_dict.items())) 
>>> sorted(filtered_dict.keys())
['carnation', 'fern', 'shamrock']
```

Comment: Problem is in the event that one of plants is "monthly", how would I exclude them from the list in the function?